# What is the Best way to "Store" data for quick and repetitous retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, memory

**Fictious Background**
I get 100 hits a minute for "the hottest car"

The hottest car always changes by the minute and its currently: "A Pinto"

Everytime I receive what the current hottest car is, I save it into a MySQL Database.

**Situation**
Everytime I get a hit for "Whats the hottest car", I need to return the answer.  I feel confident that retrieving the answer from a file vs. a DB will be faster and less work for the processor due to PHP storing the file into memory.  My concern is that if I get a new file, how do I make sure i'm returning the information in the new file and not the old information stored in memory.

P.S. If my assumptions are wrong and there is a faster way, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert (hence a comment rather than an answer) but I would suggest looking into memcached.

Comment: @Andrew: Correct, you need to cache the data somehow.

Comment: What do you mean "due to PHP storing the file into memory"?  Caching?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your assumptions. It can be tempting to assume that file access is faster, since you just have to read a file instead of connect to, query, and retrieve from a database. But bear in mind that databases are designed from the ground up for this kind of fast access to rapidly-changing information, and they have a lot of optimizations built in.

So look into caching, it is often a win, but I would not assume that file access is always faster. You can of course profile the different approaches to see if you have a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is most probably going to be invalid. MySQL has a [query cache](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Speed-Up-Queries/What-is-query-cache-in-MySQL) which keeps your query in memory. Even if not I don't think you should but using the filesystem or unless you are using `/dev/shm` because that's mapped to memory. I would use a library like [Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php) to ease the pain of caching.

But if you want to make your site really fast you should install [APC](http://scriptperfect.com/2009/09/php-and-apc-tutorial/). You should always install APC if you want your website to be fast because  caching the compiled bytecode of PHP scripts. Or use an in-memory databases [redis](http://redis.io) or [memcached](http://memcached.org), because these are even better in memory databases. redis is the easiest to install only using make and you don't need any ROOT permission either.

**P.S:** You should check out [this redis tutorial](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) because it is really powerful in-memory database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it would be a bad idea to store that information in a file.  The biggest problem is file read locks.  If one person tries to get the file while another person is getting it, there's a conflict and a fatal error.

You really should go the database route, especially if you're planning on persisting the older "hottest cars".  And if performance is a concern, you should look into PHP caching (see @Andrew's comment).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a DB/file it should be the fastest way if you directly access the memory: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Answer (score 0):

Memcache, memcache, memcache!

https://www.php.net/memcached